# JavaScriptCore Won't Pass string as NSObject *

Tags: javascript, ios, javascriptcore

Consider the following JSExported objective-c class with an NSObject * property:

```
@protocol MyObjectExport <JSExport>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *myProperty;
@end

@interface MyObject : NSObject <MyObjectExport>
@end

@implementation MyObject
- (NSObject *)myProperty
{
    NSLog(@"in myProperty");
    return nullptr;
}
- (void)setMyProperty:(NSObject *)myProperty
{
    NSLog(@"in setMyProperty");
}
@end
```

If I execute this code:

```
{
    JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
    context[@"myObject"] = [[MyObject alloc] init];
    [context evaluateScript:@"var foo = myObject.myProperty; myObject.myProperty = foo;"];
}
```

Both myProperty and setMyProperty are called.

But if I execute this code:

```
{
    JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
    context[@"myObject"] = [[MyObject alloc] init];
    [context evaluateScript:@"myObject.myProperty = \"foo\";"];
}
```

setMyProperty is not called, presumably because "foo" is not compatible with NSObject *.

However, if I execute this code:

```
{
    MyObject *myObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];
    myObject.myProperty = @"foo";
}
```

setMyProperty is called.

Of course, if I replace NSObject * with NSString *, everything works fine.  But I need this property to be able to hold a variety of object types.

I don't control what is passed to evaluateScript.  However, is there a way that I can code things so that JavaScriptCore will universally convert "foo" to an NSString * prior to passing it to the objective-c callback?  I realize I can intercept the call on the javascript side and do the necessary fiddling there, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to hold one of many types you should use `id` rather than `NSObject *`. This will make it a generic pointer kind of like a `void *` in C.

Even better you could use a `JSValue *` as the type since the `-[JSValue is*]` messages can help you figure out what type was actually passed. The downside of this though is that your `JSValue *` properties need to be backed by `JSManagedValue *` ivars to prevent retain cycles. See WWDC 2013 video 615, about 2/3 of the way through for more on this memory management issue.

Comment: He shouldn't us JSValue as a property on an objective-c object. It will cause retain cycles. He could use a JSManagedValue, though.

Comment: @TechZen You can use JSValue as a property, and in fact the video does so. Remember that the type of a property is just the type that the setter takes and the getter returns, not necessarily the type of the ivar used to store the property. It is easy to have a property of type JSValue that accesses ivars of type JSManagedValue. This was what my suggestion was aimed at.

Comment: Ah, yes, you could although it's seems a good way to shoot you foot off.

Comment: @TechZen I respectfully disagree. The idea of object oriented programming is to separate interface from implementation through encapsulation. JSManagedValue was introduced to solve a problem of storage, but users of your class do not (and should not) care about how you store your JSValues (via a JSManagedValue ivar, the implementation), only how to access them (via a JSValue property, the interface).